# Flipped image on webcam CNF129

Tags: 12.04, skype, webcam, asus

I'm using CNF129 Chicony webcam, which is built in to my ASUS K50IJ notebook, with Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. Skype shows a flipped image. I've tried every solution on the web but none works.

Any new ideas about this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You may want to edit your question to include information and/or links to what you've tried already. That may help us to figure out what the problem is...or at least to avoid giving you advice you already know doesn't work.